# Ambiguity comes with an expensive [price] tag

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

After reviewing some questions in the [shipping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shipping) tag during burnination, I ran across [price](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/price) tag, and wondered how relevant it is for SO. It has 882 questions at the time of writing this post about wildly different topics, some of them off-topic.

It has a [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/price/info) ambiguous per itself, as it refers to multiple concepts at once (currency values, a metaphoric context, and what actually is better referred as algorithmic costs in programming).

It is also a close friend to the burninated [pricing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pricing) tag.

Looking at the [Burnination Criteria](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination):

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

It is about questions somehow related to prices. It can refer to multiple types of problems and questions:

- displaying a price ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74993764/how-to-display-prices-under-products-after-login-wordpress)), we have [currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/currency) for questions about displaying currency
- calculating a price ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75030858/i-cannot-calculate-a-price-with-php))
- changing prices ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74933168/price-change-in-cart))
- prices in a trading context ([example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74862755/creating-a-price-alert-on-trading-view-using-pine-dividing-one-stock-price-by-a), [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553314/how-to-fetch-stock-price-from-australia-stock-exchange), [example 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74638526/getting-expired-options-contract-pricing-from-interactive-brokers)), these are better suited with a more specific tag like [stock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stock) or [trading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trading)
- creating pricing pages ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69126305/when-creating-a-pricing-page-for-my-android-app-how-do-you-set-price-based-on-c))
- even off-topic / commercial related questions like cloud charges ([example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74563720/i-want-to-undo-my-mistakes-on-firebase-blaze-charges), [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72072898/does-google-firebase-charge-for-inactive-user-accounts)) or licensing costs ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74518474/how-can-l-get-cplex-licensed-version))

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Prices on their own are off-topic since they do not relate to programming whatsoever.

- Asking about what is the price for something or which price to set for a good is certainly off-topic.
- Asking about how to display a price means really asking about displaying a [currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/currency) value (not necessarily a price, can also be for example an account balance).
- Asking about how to calculate a price is on-topic, but the [price](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/price) tag on it doesn't add many meaningful information since the problem will most likely be related with the algorithm, formula, working with floating point values, or something else.
- I don't think there can be any domain experts in the abstract concept of a price (there may be for stock prices, currency formats, etc, but we have more specific tags for these).

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Not really. It describes that the question contains something about a price, but the problem will usually not be the price itself, rather managing to display/calculate/change it.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

The tag wiki is very good at telling it is not the case:

- **Usually** an amount of currency paid in exchange for a product or service.
- Sometimes "the price to pay" is meant metaphorically.
- In programming context, the price for a change to a program refers to an increased amount of memory consumption, execution duration, latency, worst case behaviour or any other undesirable attribute of the program afterwards.

But there two main different meanings found searching in the questions, and while they are similar, I don't think there is enough overlap between them:

- the price for commercial goods
- prices in a trading context

Somebody expert in calculating the price of a cart might not really know about sending trading orders, and vice versa.

> Is it causing harm?

While *most* of the questions are indeed programming questions somehow related to prices, the tag is also a hook for asking questions about prices of programs and commercial support inquiries that are off topic for this site ([example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74518474/how-can-l-get-cplex-licensed-version), [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72072898/does-google-firebase-charge-for-inactive-user-accounts)).

Should we burninate this tag?

Comment: "Time has come to pay the [price]"

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine [ambiguity](https://aclanthology.org/E99-1018/) is an information theory metric.

Comment: The [price] is Wrong

Comment: Becoming [price]less.

Comment: The [price] we are paying for this tag is too high, its time to exit...

Comment: "You can't put a [price] tag on SO posts".

Comment: Burninate it with fire

Comment: The [price] tag is too expensive